# Don't see any calls to the Callable.call() method but the code inside call() method still got executed, where was the call() method been called?

Tags: java, methods, callable

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to learn the interface ScheduledExecutorService. I saw the code below online.

I don't see any calls to the Callable.call() method, but the code inside call() method still got executed. Where has the call() method been called?

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

ScheduledFuture sf1 = ses1.schedule(new Callable() {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("executed!");
        return "called";
    }
},
        2,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);

ses1.shutdown();
```

Output:

```
executed!
```

Comment: _"I dont see any calls to the Callable.call() method"_ -- where did you look? Please visit the [help] and also read [ask] to learn what information should be provided in a question.  The executor service called it for you, as it is supposed to do. It's not at all clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in `ScheduledExecutorService` called `schedule()` does the following, according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> Creates and executes a one-shot action that becomes enabled after the given delay.

The first argument can either be a `Callable` or a `Runnable`.  In either case, when the time out expires, the `ScheduledExecutorService` will invoke the `Callable's` `call()` method or the Runnable's `run()` method.

It's just what executor services do.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the schedule method API, you'll find out that your call method will be executed after 2 seconds.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable command,
                      long delay,
                      TimeUnit unit)
```

Creates and executes a one-shot action that becomes enabled after the given delay.